# Keeping Dates in R Time Series YY/MM/DD Format

Tags: r, time-series

I created a time series in R and the dates have been removed from the data as it has been converted into a univariate time series, I did this by entering the following command

```
new.ts <- ts(new[,"Daily"]),start=c(2002-03-21))
```

How do I keep the date format that is used in my original dataframe which is of the form, YYYY-MM-DD?

Thank you.

Comment: The `Date `class format is `YYYY-MM-DD` and all others are `character` class or `factor` (depending upon how you read it)

Comment: `ts` does not have specific support for dates. You can use the zoo or xts packages.

Comment: FYI, `c(2002-03-21)` is not a date, it's a number, and that number is 1978; while that also looks like a date (a year, actually), it's just a number as well ... the math of subtracting 3 from 2002, and then subtracting 21 from that difference. You should instead use a real `Date` class there, likely.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Try the tsibble package

Comment: You can convert your univariate back to dates using something like `as.Date(x, origin=as.Date('1970-01-01'))` when `x` is the univariate value. But fix your univarite conversion first. Computers don't use dates like people do, as such the format only matters so you can tell the computer how to convert a `string` ("2002-03-21") into a `Date`. From then on the computer treats the date as a number (in R a `Date` counts the number of days before or after 01JAN1970). The displayed `string` with format is for human consumption only.